# "Expression.Lambda" in "where" return error "has some invalid arguments"

Tags: c#, lambda, compiler-errors

I want to use dynamic expression for creating an advanced search in my app. I read some article about the expression and write this code :

```
var result = //my query
    from filter in context.Filters
    join customer in context.Customers on filter.customerId equals customer.id
    select new { customer, filter };

var paramCustomer = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Models.Customer), "customer");
var paramFilter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Models.Filter), "filter");
var pName = Expression.Property(paramCustomer, "name");
var pInstallDate = Expression.Property(paramFilter, "installDate");
var con1 = Expression.OrElse(

    Expression.Equal(pName, Expression.Constant("ASD"))
        ,
    Expression.Equal(pInstallDate, Expression.Constant(13920505))

);

var con2 = Expression.AndAlso(

    Expression.Equal(pName, Expression.Constant("ABC"))
        ,
    con1

);

var exp1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<Models.Customer, Models.Filter, bool>>(con2, new ParameterExpression[] { paramCustomer, paramFilter });

Console.WriteLine(
    exp1 //output: (customer, filter) => ((customer.name == "ABC") AndAlso ((customer.name == "ASD") OrElse (filter.installDate == 1392)))
);

Console.WriteLine(
    result.Where(exp1) //error
);
```

I want add dynamic expression to my query but I get these errors :

> Error 7 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error 8 Argument 2: cannot convert from  'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' to 'System.Func'

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. By selecting `new { customer, filter }` you are selecting a new **anonymous type** which is not the same as a Func taking two arguments. Your Func would have to take ONE argument, and that argument would have to be an anonymous type which matched the one you are selecting... But thay isn't going to be possible with the Expression API. Select a new concrete model or a tuple which can be the first (and only) argument to your expression (which would then need to be modified to access those individual properties)

Comment: thanks. please give an example ...